# How to remove the fbclid paramter in SvelteKit

Tags: facebook, sveltekit

at the moment, the issue is that Facebook `fbclid` queries look atrocious on my otherwise very nice URLs.

I WANT THEM GONE

*solution below*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution that i could find was to use a [handle hook](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#handle) to remove it if it's there.

```
import type { Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const handle: Handle = ({ event, resolve }) => {
    let assign: any = {};

    if (event.request.url.match(/\?fbclid=.+/)) {
        assign = {
            redirected: true,
            headers: {
                Location: event.request.url.replace(/[\?&]fbclid=[^&]+/, '')
            }
        };
    }

    let r = resolve(event);
    Object.assign(r, assign);
    return r;
};
```

the key part of this code here is the `/[\\?&]fbclid=[^&]+/` which allows other query parameters to exist, this will only remove the `fbclid` parameter as shown on [regexr](https://regexr.com/6j2s0)

I hope this helps :)